# Does declaring an extern variable make a copy of it?

Tags: c, variables

Let's say I have:

### file1.c

```
uint8_t array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

### main.c

```
extern uint8_t array[];
```

Does this create a copy of the variable array in main.c?

Comment: Why'd you think it'd make a copy? what did you study about `extern` keyword?

Comment: Declaring something only tells the compilers that "something" exists *somewhere*.

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question. I read that it creates a reference, but after I declared an extern variable in one of my sources the compiler started telling me that the code was 260 bytes too big and I got confused. Turned out to be something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it tells the linker "there's a variable somewhere with this name, please fill in a reference to it whenever it's mentioned".

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! I still have a lot to learn about the site. I apologize again.